# FXML Слишком много функций в классе-контроллере

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

В процессе использования JavaFX и программы SceneBuilder столкнулся с таким вопросом:

В окне показывается одновременно 14 кнопок, каждой из которых в SceneBuilder (в FXML) соответствует свой метод (т.е. их всего 14 штук различных методов внутри класса-контроллера).
Каждая кнопка обращается к одному и тому же классу, но совершает разные действия, при этом каждая из них в конце обращается к методу, выводящему что-то вроде отчета.

Обоснован ли такой подход с 14 методами? Может есть какой-нибудь более оптимальный способ?

Код:

```
@FXML
private void openGatePressed()
{
    this.fwork.createGate(false); // Обращение к тому "общему" классу
    this.ancientPaneArrange(); // Перерисовка окна
    this.checkAftermath("gate"); // "общее" действие, выводящее отчет
} // И таких ещё 13 штук с разными методами у fwork и разными аргументами у checkAftermath
```

Comment: Не оптимальней, но можно повесить один метод на все кнопки `pressed(ActionEvent event)` и парсить по `(Button)event.getSource()`. Кстати, судя по названию метода вы используете `onMousePressed`( не понятно почему не `onAction` ) - тогда можете свой "отчет" перенести в `onMouseReleased`, хотя зачем?

Comment: На самом деле, они действуют по onAction, это просто название так выбрано, возможно, неудачно.
А парсинг осуществлять через switch-case? Или есть более элегантный способ?

Comment: Я просто предложил возможный вариант, но на самом деле сам бы наверное не использовал, многое зависит от архитектуры приложения.